# ASP.NET MVC 4.5 WebSocket server loses connection after a few messages have been transferred

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, websocket

I've just started to play around with WebSockets and ASP.NET and have run into a weird issue. I'm building a very primitive ASP.NET 4.5 WebAPI application that is supposed to function as an echo-server like so:

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebSockets;
// ...

namespace MyControllers
{
    internal class EchoHandler : WebSocketHandler
    {
        public override void OnClose()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Close"); 
        }

        public override void OnError()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Error: " + this.Error.ToString()); 
        }

        public override void OnOpen()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Open"); 
        }

        public override void OnMessage(string message)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Message: " + message);
            this.Send("Echo: " + message);
        }
    }

    public class EchoController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new EchoHandler());
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm connecting to this service using a Windows Store Application written in C#. The relevant code looks like this:

```
class WebsocketTest
{
    private MessageWebSocket webSocket;
    private DataWriter messageWriter;

    private async Task Connect()
    {
        var server = new Uri("ws://127.0.0.1:81/");

        webSocket = new MessageWebSocket();
        webSocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;
        webSocket.MessageReceived += messageWebSocket_MessageReceived;
        webSocket.Closed += messageWebSocket_Closed;

        await webSocket.ConnectAsync(server);
        messageWebSocket = webSocket;
        messageWriter = new DataWriter(webSocket.OutputStream);
    }

    private async Task Send(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            messageWriter.WriteString(message);

            await messageWriter.StoreAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = WebSocketError.GetStatus(ex.GetBaseException().HResult);
        }
    }
}
```

This works well for a while, but after an arbitrary number of messages have been sent back and forth, OnError() is invoked on the server and I get the following exception: "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request" (It's the "this.Send(...)" that seems to be causing it). If I keep sending stuff on the client, I get a "ConnectionAborted" error when calling "dataWriter.StoreAsync()". 
The error occurs every time, but it takes a varying number of messages before it does. Using longer messages seems to speed up the process.

For testing, I also tried using plain AspNetWebSockets instead of a WebSocketHandler but with the same outcome.

Any ideas?

Thanks a ton in advance,
Kai

Answer (score 0):

**Its a bug** (reported by me):
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/976851/server-websocket-closed-abruptly-the-i-o-operation-has-been-aborted-because-of-either-a-thread-exit-or-an-application-request

I have been trying to find a workaround for quite some time without being successful. I'm using the `HttpListener` but the symptom is the same. Now I have changed implementation to a third party library and the problem seems to have been resolved.